# git deleted tags keep coming back

Tags: git

Trying to delete unwanted tags from a repository, but they keep coming back!

```
$ git push -d origin v0.8.1
To XXXX
 - [deleted]         v0.8.1

$ git push -d origin v0.8.1
error: unable to delete 'v0.8.1': remote ref does not exist

$ git push -d origin v1.2.1
Enumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 164 bytes | 164.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0)
To XXXX
 - [deleted]         v1.2.1
 * [new tag]         v0.8.1 -> v0.8.1

$ git push -d origin v0.8.1
Enumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 165 bytes | 165.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0)
To XXXX
 - [deleted]         v0.8.1
 * [new tag]         v1.2.1 -> v1.2.1
```

...and I can keep going round and round forever!

git version: 2.25.1

Is this a bug in git or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: I assume you did not delete the refs locally and are just pushing them again with the second push.

Comment: Oh! Now it all makes sense!